# Live Edit in Webstorm 8 with remote Server

Tags: zend-framework, vagrant, webstorm, remote-server, liveedit

I want to use Live Edit in Webstorm.

I have the following configuration:

- Webstorm 8
- PHP App with Zend Framework
  -Test Server created with Vagrant on remote LAN Host, DNS configured to "subdomain.localhost" in hosts file
- Changed Files are deployed via FTP to Vagrant VM
- I configured the Debug Configuation with the "Javascript Debug" default and set the URL to "http://subdomain.localhost"
- I enabled "Live Edit" in "Menu->View"
- I checked "Enable live editing" and "Highlight current element in browser..." in "Settings->Live Edit"

Now the problem is that the views of the zend implementation "*.phtml" aren't updated on change, but element highlighting is working on the rendered views.

Also if i change css or javascript in public folder, nothing updates live.

So my question is, how do i configure this environment properly, so the live editing works with html, css and javascript.

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused... WebStorm provides no support for PHP/Zend Framework - I'm not sure what your configuration looks like... Note also that javascript changes are not always 'live' (see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033586/webstorm-live-edit-not-working-for-an-external-javascript-file) and live update for linked CSS doesn't work in WebStorm 8 ([WEB-11393](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11393))

Comment: We use phpstorm for backend-development. I am using Webstorm for Front-End development.